# Oracle - Copy Rows but Increment Date up to a Max Date given various Starting Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table currently that is populated similar to the below, and a max date, say *31/01/2023*

| Name | Start Date | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 01/01/2023 | Red |
| Mike | 12/01/2023 | Blue |

How can I duplicate the rows but incrementally increase the date similar to below output without breaking the max date for any Name, Colour Pairs?

| Name | Start Date | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 01/01/2023 | Red |
| Dan | 02/01/2023 | Red |
|  | . |  |
|  | . |  |
|  | . |  |
| Dan | 31/01/2023 | Red |
| Mike | 12/01/2023 | Blue |
| Mike | 13/01/2023 | Blue |
|  | . |  |
|  | . |  |
|  | . |  |
| Mike | 31/01/2023 | Blue |

Not sure how to loop through when length of each startdate to max date will be different length

Answer (score 0):

That's a *row generator*; one option is - with sample data as

```
SQL> with
  2  test (name, start_date, colour) as
  3    (select 'Dan' , date '2023-01-01', 'Red'  from dual union all
  4     select 'Mike', date '2023-01-10', 'Blue' from dual
  5    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  6  select name, start_date + column_value - 1 as start_date, colour
  7  from test cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= date '2023-01-31' - start_date + 1
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by name, start_date;

NAME START_DATE COLOUR
---- ---------- ------
Dan  01/01/2023 Red
Dan  02/01/2023 Red
Dan  03/01/2023 Red
Dan  04/01/2023 Red
<snip>
Dan  28/01/2023 Red
Dan  29/01/2023 Red
Dan  30/01/2023 Red
Dan  31/01/2023 Red
Mike 10/01/2023 Blue
Mike 11/01/2023 Blue
Mike 12/01/2023 Blue
<snip>
Mike 29/01/2023 Blue
Mike 30/01/2023 Blue
Mike 31/01/2023 Blue

53 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause (also called a recursive CTE):

```sql
WITH recursive_subquery (name, start_date, colour, end_date) AS (
  SELECT name, start_date, colour, DATE '2023-01-31' FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT name, start_date + 1, colour, end_date
  FROM   recursive_subquery
  WHERE  start_date + 1 <= end_date
) SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY name SET order_id
SELECT name, start_date, colour
FROM   recursive_subquery;
```

*(Note: instead of using `SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY name SET order_id` in the recursive sub-query, you could use `ORDER BY name, start_date` on the final `SELECT`.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, start_date, colour) AS
  SELECT 'Dan',  DATE '2023-01-01', 'Red'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', DATE '2023-01-10', 'Blue' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | START_DATE | COLOUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Red |
| Dan | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | Red |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Dan | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 | Red |
| Dan | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | Red |
| Mike | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | Blue |
| Mike | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | Blue |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Mike | 2023-01-30 00:00:00 | Blue |
| Mike | 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | Blue |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/speL5sU2)